# 'tell application "Finder" to restart' brings up WorkflowServiceRunner.xpc wants to make changes

Tags: applescript, finder

I wrote reboot scripts for both Snow Leopard and Lion to quickly boot between them.

SL script works fine, but it seems Lion has some additional security feature that requires a password when script is run.

I get a dialog requesting my password that says:
"WorkflowServiceRunner.xpc wants to make changes. Type your password to allow this"

Is there a way in code to send pw info so this runs automatically?

Comment: Please post your code...

Comment: do shell script "bless --device /dev/disk0s2 -setBoot -nextonly" password "<password>" with administrator privileges
tell application "Finder" to restart

Answer (score 0):

You mean you had to type your password because of `tell application "Finder" to restart`?
In that case, you can use

```
do shell script "killall Finder"
tell application "Finder" to open
```